# Very simple regular expression question regarding "assertions"

Tags: regex, string, pattern-matching

I want a regular expression that matches the following

```
example.com -> matches, returns example.com
foo-bar.com -> matches, returns foo-bar.com

www.example.com -> does not match
www.foo-bar.com -> does not match
```

Easy? I just need the PERL compatible regular expression that tests if the string does not begin with `www.`, and if so, captures and returns the whole string.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be able to use this:

```
 /^(?!www\.)(.*)$/
```

Explanation:

- The `^` and `$` [anchor](http://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html) the match, so it has to match the entire string given.
- `(?!www\.)` is a [negative lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html), which blocks the match if the string starts with `www.`.
- The `(.*)` [captures](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html) the entirety of the string.

Comment: @Salman: I've tried to write a short explanation of the regex.

Comment: positive lookaheads, negative lookaheads, positive lookbehinds, negative lookbehinds... time for coffee!!!